# how to make an entry widget have a list of integers to choose from

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

so I'm new to Tkinter and I have no sample code for you to look at but I do have one question, which is how to make an entry widget have a limited amount of integers to choose from e.g:

when clicking on the input box, it gives options to choose certain integers like
[1] [2] [3] and so on

Comment: You wouldn't use an entry widget for this. Probably a drop down menu. If you are really stuck on using an entry widget you can use a validation method to restrict the numbers allowed to be used.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#combobox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a dropdown menu from a List in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441885/how-can-i-create-a-dropdown-menu-from-a-list-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441885/how-can-i-create-a-dropdown-menu-from-a-list-in-tkinter) for more information

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one") # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()

mainloop()
```