# Python tkinter: How to place a dropdown menu when button pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, drop-down-menu

I want to show a dropdown menu when `myBtn` is pressed but don't know how.

```
myBtn = Button(self, image=BoxImg.png, bd=0, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
```

`BoxImg.png`:

[image]

So when this image is pressed (Which is the button) I want it to show something like this where every line is clickable:

[image]

I found this method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442534/14698534) and the only problem with it is that, to show the dropdown menu we should press on this thing: [image] (that isn't a button), but I want it to be a button so that I can configure to it the image `BoxImg.png` (`Btn.configure(image='BoxImg.png')`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a dropdown menu from a List in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441885/how-can-i-create-a-dropdown-menu-from-a-list-in-tkinter)

Comment: @RyanZhang no cause here it's not a button that's used, to show the dropdown menu we should press on [this thing](https://ibb.co/g6VptPr), but I want it to be a button so that I can configure to it the image `BoxImg.png`

Comment: Try using `Menubutton`.

Comment: Instead of `ttk.Menubutton` try `tk.Menubutton(self, indicatoron = 0, direction = "below", compound = tk.LEFT, relief = "groove", image = image)`. This will give you a button like object with potential for an image.