# Is there a way to create a dropdown menu using the graphics library in python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a graphical interface for users for a program I built for generating a few basic reports using sales data. One of the features is being able to search for specific sales using any of the criterias available in the dataset. I wanted to use a dropdown menu so the user can select any of the available criterias and then type what the are looking for in a entry box but I haven't figured out how to create a dropdown menu. Any ideas on how I could implement this?

I tried making it work like I would using Tkinter but that didn't work.

```
    def search_sales_gui(self):
        search_sale_menu = GraphWin("Search Sales", 400, 300)
        text = Text(Point(100, 30), "Search Sales")
        text.setSize(18)
        text.draw(search_sale_menu)

        criteria_label = Text(Point(30, 70), "Search Criteria:")
        criteria_label.draw(search_sale_menu)

        # Define the list of search criteria
        search_criteria = ["Purchase ID", "Item Sold", "Customer Details", "Country"]

        # Create an OptionMenu for the search criteria
        criteria_var = StringVar(search_sale_menu)
        criteria_var.set(search_criteria[0])  # Set default value
        criteria_dropdown = OptionMenu(search_sale_menu, criteria_var, *search_criteria)
        criteria_dropdown.config(width=15)
        criteria_dropdown.place(x=100, y=70)

        keyword_entry = Entry(Point(100, 110), 20)
        keyword_entry.draw(search_sale_menu)
        keyword_label = Text(Point(30, 110), "Keyword:")
        keyword_label.draw(search_sale_menu)

        search_button = Rectangle(Point(70, 160), Point(130, 190))
        search_button.setFill("lightblue")
        search_button.draw(search_sale_menu)
        search_text = Text(Point(100, 175), "Search")
        search_text.draw(search_sale_menu)

        while True:
            click_point = search_sale_menu.getMouse()
            if search_button.getP1().getX() < click_point.getX() < search_button.getP2().getX() \
                    and search_button.getP1().getY() < click_point.getY() < search_button.getP2().getY():
                selected_criteria = criteria_var.get()
                keyword = keyword_entry.getText()
                # Perform search based on selected_criteria and keyword
                # Implement the logic to search for sales using the selected criteria and keyword
                break
```

Comment: Do you mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441885/how-can-i-create-a-dropdown-menu-from-a-list-in-tkinter ?

Comment: You say Tinkter didn't work!  What specifically didn't work?  Providing sample input data, expected output will help to clarify your problem and allow us to help, as presented, your question is not answerable within the bounds of this site.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for replying, as trozzel pointed out this is my first post so sorry if my question wasn't worded properly. As for your question itprorh66, what I meant is that I tried implementing a drop down menu the same way I would if I was using Tkinter but since my professor only allows us to use the graphics library I was wondering if there is a similar function to easily create a dropdown menu in the graphics library.

To make it clearer, I am forced to use the graphics library by my professor and would like to create a dropdown menu like the one Tkinter has. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean when you say "graphics library", maybe this is related to [tag:zelle-graphics]? If you're asking about a module that is not well known, you should link to it.